# Create A XMLSchema for String

Tags: c#

I want to Create XMLSchema for String ,

```
     String parameter="<root><HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName>
<AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><PlaceNumber>38</PlaceNumber></root>"
```

we can add some more elements to it automatically.then How to Create XMLSchema for that .

as we have static Schema for above string will be

```
@"<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<xs:element name=""root"">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name=""HostName"" type=""xs:string"" />
        <xs:element name=""AdminUserName"" type=""xs:string"" />
        <xs:element name=""AdminPassword"" type=""xs:string"" />
        <xs:element name=""PlaceNumber"" type=""xs:positiveInteger"" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element></xs:schema>"
```

If i Add more elements to string Parameter . How can i generate Schema on Run?.

Comment: The xml string supplied is not valid XML. You must have a root element

Comment: Ok, If i Add root element is it possible for generating Scema on run? what we need to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try reading it with a `DataSet`, writing the schema and finally tweaking a little bit the XML structure.

```
class Program
{
    const string
        MinOccurs = "minOccurs",
        Element = "element",
        LocalName = "xs";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String parameter =
            @"<HostName>Arasanalu</HostName>
              <AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName>
              <AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword>
              <PlaceNumber>38</PlaceNumber>";
        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new StringReader("<root>" + parameter + "</root>"));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var w = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            ds.WriteXmlSchema(w);

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
        doc.Root.LastNode.Remove();
        doc.Root.Attributes()
            .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName != LocalName).Remove();
        doc.Descendants(XName.Get(Element, 
            doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(LocalName).NamespaceName))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(e =>
            {
                var minOccurs = e.Attribute(XName.Get(MinOccurs));
                if (minOccurs != null)
                    minOccurs.Remove();
            });
        sb.Clear();
        doc.Save(w);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks: It will work if you have correct XML elements.